# exported .java files assistance

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I am in need of some help. I am a programming student and we are required to use Netbeans for this class which I never used before. I worked a very long time of a project and finally completed it. I hit file, export to zip and saved the file. I now have a file that has no type of extension. That would have been ok if my son did not mess with the laptop and delete the src folder where the .java files are. So now I have a file that has my work but when I open it in notepad++ it looks like it is compressed or encrypted. How can I open this file to get my work back. I have to turn this in tomorrow and I worked a couple of days to get this to work properly.
PS, I searched the files high and low and cannot find the src files.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding .zip to the filename and trying to unzip it?  Most java-related archives use essentially the same compression as zip so you can open .jar, .war, etc files with zip utilities.

Comment: I just did, it opened but there were no .java files? it has a folder "nbproject", a build.xml and a manifest.mf. can i use those to get my code back?

Comment: Do you have .class files left if you have build the project anytime?

Comment: I cannot find those either. I am not sure how they just disappeared. I retrieved everything close in the recycle bin and looked through everything based on modify time. I kept saving every few minutes but all the ones that were modified today are not it... am i missing something?

Comment: then the only way which occurs to me is use a deleted data retrieving software on your system. It can fetch the data back if you r lucky.

Comment: "I hit file, export to zip and saved the file. I now have a file that has no type of extension" Also try opening the zip in winrar or some zip software

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I got it now, I added .zip to the end and it opened up. the src file needed more digging because it was not there for some reason but I finally found it and put it back, ran the program and all is good. Thanks again for your help.